# Datatype attribure implementation

Tags: .net

In my property i need a email address validation. But `[Datatype(DataType.EmailAddress)]` was not working. How to rectify the same.

Answer (score 0):

While you aren't being too clear on where you need to perform the validation, but assuming you had a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

The validation of the `EmailAddress` property does not occur on the setting of the property.

However, you can trigger the validation by using the methods on the [`Validator` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validator.aspx):

```
// The instance.
var myClass = new MyClass { EmailAddress = "someone@somewhere.com", };

// The context for validation.
var context = new ValidationContext(myClass, null, null);

// Validates the property.
Validator.ValidateValue(myClass.EmailAddress, context, 
    new ValidationAttribute[] { new DataTypeAttribute(DataType.EmailAddress), });
```

Of course, that defeats the purpose of declaring the attribute on the class declaration.  You can validate the entire class state like so:

```
// Using same myClass and context declarations:
Validator.ValidateObject(myClass, context);
```

If you prefer to not to `try/catch Exception` instances, then you can use the `Try*` versions of the `Validate` methods instead.